# Tailwindcss: fixed/sticky footer on the bottom

Tags: css, django, tailwind-css

I use tailwindCSS and confront a problem with make footer.

**base.html**

```
  <body>
    {% include "partials/nav.html" %}

    {% block content %}
    {% endblock %}

    {% include "partials/footer.html" %}
  </body>
```

**footer.html**

```
<footer class="w-full h-64 bg-gray-900 static bottom-0">
        {% load static %}
        <img src="{% static "images/logo_white.png" %}" width="70px"> <p class="text-white"> &copy~~~~~~</p>
</footer>
```

i tried static,absolute,fixed,relative... but .fixed cover the content block and relative make footer going upside. or .mb-0, .bottom-0 doesn't work.

is it possible make footer fixed on the bottom?

Answer (score 251, accepted):

```
<div class="flex flex-col h-screen justify-between">
  <header class="h-10 bg-red-500">Header</header>
  <main class="mb-auto h-10 bg-green-500">Content</main>
  <footer class="h-10 bg-blue-500">Footer</footer>
</div>
```

Class `justify-between` is not required, but I would leave him (for other case).

So, play with `h-screen` and `mb-auto` classes.

And you get this UI:

[image]

Comment: This is quite a classy solution but if you want to apply page-wide classes with this setup (like background color) you need to set it for each element separately.

Comment: If the page is short in content .. it does not go very buttom

Comment: @HosMercury for me it does, all i did was "flex flex-col h-screen justify-between"
if i remove "justify-between" then it does not go very bottom

Comment: This is not a sticky footer, this is just a footer.  If the content is taller than the screen then it just pushes the footer down.  https://codepen.io/therms/pen/BaREVNN

Comment: I just ran into a similar situation and I was able to make the footer sticky by adding the following tailwind classes "sticky bottom-0"

Comment: @DustinWyatt Sorry, but this is exactly what a "Sticky Footer" is supposed to be. Google "Sticky Footers"

"A sticky footer pattern is one where the footer of your page "sticks" to the bottom of the viewport in cases where the content is shorter than the viewport height."

Comment: Use `min-h-screen` instead. If you use `h-screen` and set the footer height (eg. `h-20`), when the height of the content overflows the screen, the footer's height isn't correct anymore!

Comment: This is *exactly* what I was looking for. Kudos!

Every js UI kit should have this as a super simple example of how to set up a real sticky footer.

Comment: For those for whom flex is too much, there are some solutions below that don't need them.

Answer (score 125):

Another approach would be using **flex-grow**.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tailwindcss/2.0.2/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="flex flex-col h-screen">
    <div class="bg-red-500">header</div>
    <div class="bg-green-500 flex-grow">content</div>
    <div class="bg-blue-500">footer</div>
</div>
```

Comment: flex-grow in TailwindCSS 3 is now: `grow`

Answer (score 52):

New solution in 2022. Tailwindcss version 3.0.24 in codepen demo.

```html
<div class="min-h-screen">
  <div>Content</div>
  <div class="sticky top-[100vh]">Footer</div>
</div>
```

[codepen demo](https://codepen.io/shrekuu/pen/zYRovQa)

Comment: Didn't work for me.

Comment: Worked great for me! Thanks.

Comment: @MariaCampbell does the codepen demo i linked to work?

Comment: Didn't work for me.

Answer (score 39):

use 'fixed' instead of 'static'

`class="fixed bottom-0"`

Comment: how to add this property only when on mobile devices?

Comment: @Apoorvpandey I am quite new to tailwind CSS also, but here is the link to tailwind css document  how to  target mobile devices https://tailwindcss.com/docs/responsive-design#targeting-mobile-screens

Answer (score 26):

Another way that was recently discovered by [Sílvio Rosa](https://www.twitter.com/silvior_) uses `position: sticky` + `top: 100vh` on the footer. The way to achieve this with **TailWindCSS** is...

```
<html class="min-h-screen">
  <body class="min-h-screen">
    
    <header>Header</header>
    <main>Content</main>
    <footer class="sticky top-[100vh]">footer</footer>

  </body>
</html>
```

You can read the full article on CSS Tricks [here](https://css-tricks.com/a-clever-sticky-footer-technique/)

Answer (score 11):

## Sticky Header and Footer

For a **sticky** header and footer **regardless of content and screen size**, do this:

```
<div class="flex flex-col h-screen">
    <div class="sticky top-0 z-50">header</div>
    <div class="grow">content</div>
    <div class="sticky bottom-0 z-50">footer</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 10):

None of the solutions here worked for me since my component wasn't a layout component. I wanted a sticky footer to appear on just a single page and it needed to ignore the margins and padding of parent containers.  Here's the tailwind solution that worked for me:

```
<div className="fixed bottom-0 left-0 bg-red-500 w-screen h-12">
  Sticks to bottom, covers width of screen
</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

A solution without using margin:

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  display: none !important; /* just to hide stackoverflow console warning */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

<div class="flex flex-col min-h-screen">
  <header class="bg-yellow-600">content</header>
  <div class="bg-blue-600">content</div>
  <div class="flex-1"></div> <!-- here -->
  <footer class="bg-red-400">footer</footer>
</div>
```

Another so clever solution is using `sticky top-[100vh]` for footer. [by Chris Coyier](https://css-tricks.com/a-clever-sticky-footer-technique/)

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  display: none !important; /* just to hide stackoverflow console warning */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

<div class="min-h-screen">
  <header class="bg-yellow-600">content</header>
  <div class="bg-blue-600">content</div>
  <footer class="bg-red-400 sticky top-[100vh]">footer</footer>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

While I avoided using `display: grid` for a long time, using it seems to be the simplest solution to date (compared to the flexbox solution):

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

<!-- Wrapper element ('display: grid', 'grid-template-rows' defined) -->
<div class="min-h-screen grid grid-rows-[min-content_1fr_min-content] ">
  <header class="bg-blue-200">Header</header>
  
  <!-- Content element (display: grid) -->
  <main class="grid bg-blue-300">Content</main>
  
  <footer class="bg-blue-400">Footer</footer>
</div>
```

There are two key points:

- `min-h-screen`, `grid`, and `grid-rows-[...]`have been applied to the wrapping element<sup>1</sup>. Considering `grid-rows`, an arbitrary value has to be used (Tailwind v3 offers only evenly distributed rows). The element that should take up all available space needs to have `1fr` value; the rest is up to you (`min-content` might be the best choice).
- The element that is supposed to take up all the available space needs to have `grid` class.

---

<sup>1</sup>Alternatively, instead of `min-h-screen`, `h-full` can be used, but it needs to be applied to *all* of the wrapping elements, starting with `<html/>`.

It is actually easier **done** than **said**. Take a look at the example above.

Answer (score 2):

This has been a major pain for me recently. I ended up solving this without `flex`, I simply gave my body a min-height of 75vh and it seems to have produced the desired result.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using this:

```
<div class="min-h-screen flex flex-col justify-start">
   <div>your main content</div>
   <footer class="mt-auto">
      <div>your footer content</div>
   </footer>
</div>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

The best answer that I have seen was to set container, containing the footer, to screen height ('min-h-screen') and make it a flexbox ('flex') and set the element above the footer to flex-1 so that it would consume all the spaces and push the footer below.

In your code, it would look like these:

```html
<body class='flex flex-col min-h-screen'>
    {% include "partials/nav.html" %}
    <div class='flex-1'>
      {% block content %}
      {% endblock %}
    </div>
    {% include "partials/footer.html" %}
</body>
```

Here's a sample code for my use-case:

```html
<div className='flex flex-col min-h-screen'>
  <div className='flex-1 mx-24 mt-12'>
    <Header />
    <div className='grid grid-cols-4 gap-12 my-12'>
      {data.map( (item, i) => <Todo key={i} title={item.title} note={item.note} texts={item.texts}/>)}
    </div>
  </div>
  <Footer />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a lot simpler than what I'm seeing. Here's a sticky header and sticky footer. Always visible no matter how tall the content is:

```
<>
  <div className="sticky top-0 min-w-full">Header</div>
  <div className="min-w-full min-h-screen">SOME CONTENT</div>
  <div className="min-w-full min-h-screen">SOME CONTENT</div>
  <div className="fixed bottom-0 min-w-full">Footer</div>
</>
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on tailwind documentations, I used [positionning](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/position#statically-positioning-elements) like this:

```html
<body>
  <div class="static min-w-full min-h-screen p-1">
    <p>content<p>
    <div class="absolute bottom-0 min-w-full">
      <p>foot</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

- `static` and `absolute` allow to position child (footer) relatively to parent (content)
- `min-h-screen` tells the parent is as high as the screen
- `bottom-0` tells footer must be at the bottom of the parent

Answer (score 0):

Use the `h-[100vmin]` custom class on the first **div** inside your layout component, typically as follows:

```
<Layout>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="h-[100vmin]">
      ...
    </div>
  </div>
</Layout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<footer class="absolute bottom-0 w-full px-6 py-6 text-white bg-emerald-500">
```

I think you can just use `absolute bottom-0` to locate it, `w-full` to fill the width, and `px` and `py` to size your footer .

Answer (score 0):

To avoid breaking a bg-gradient on the `<body>`:

```
<main class="min-h-screen"></main>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<div class='relative'>
   <div class='fixed bottom-0 right-10 cursor-pointer rounded-t-3xl bg-red-500 w-10 h-10 grid content-center justify-center'>
      your text
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you edit your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?